# Creating GUI using XML in C\C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, windows, user-interface

i never actually used XML, someone can recommend me METHOD to create GUI configuration file for C\C++ application.
Recommend me framework or something, because i really dont know how what is best to use.

I code the application for Windows only, and i don't want to use framework that has dependencies on .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are open source GUI frameworks like GTK. It is platform independed. Is that something you are looking for? You could use Mono in combination with .NET to build .NET depended cross-platform applications.

Comment: You have many choice, a very common one may be QT. If you plan to build Metro applications then built-in native (unmanaged) WPF is the only choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) to generate the XML for the GUI and use the [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) toolkit ...

> By using GtkBuilder, Glade XML files can be used in numerous
>   programming languages including C, C++, C#, Vala, Java, Perl,
>   Python,and others.
>
> Glade is Free Software released under the GNU GPL License.

... and it works well even on Windows ...

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend looking at a product from the [QT project](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/index.html) called [QT Quick](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtquick.html) that uses a configuration file ([but it is not XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML)) to describe the user interface and JavaScript to handle actions and it interfaces with C++ code on the back end.

I don't think most GUIs use an XML file to describe the widgets/controls. But Mozilla has an XML based markup language that is used for creating GUIs called [XUL (XML User Interface Language)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL) . It may be possible to use it as a front end for C/C++ desktop code via some other technology called [XPCOM/XPConnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_Joy_of_XUL).

I was at a presentation in which someone stated that using HTML5 (must be HTML-5) along with Javascript and a browser would replace traditional GUI toolkits as the front end for a C++ desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Thought, windows programmers may use internal(!) windows interfaces. Choose one from [XMLDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [xmllite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx).